# Farsi violenza: come interpretare e usare quest'espressione

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, meaning, phrase-request

Una mia mica usa l'espressione "farsi violenza" come un'tipo di azione che porta ad un risultato positivo. Ma io associo la violenza ad un fatto negativo. Quindi faccio fatica sia ad usare che ad interpretare il significato di questa espressione. Mi chiedo se qualcuno ai può essermi di aiuto.

Grazie.

Comment: Nella domanda ci sono dei refusi: mica (amica), un'tipo (un tipo), ai (eliminare).

Comment: [Pagina 636](https://books.google.it/books?id=mOosAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA636&lpg=PA636&dq=farsi+violenza&source=bl&ots=3BuiKBy3Lm&sig=8XLgL3a3Eo_1BE4iEGUGEkwRo-Y&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4tsz9rMLVAhXHLlAKHZqbBhAQ6AEIITAC#v=onepage&q=farsi%20violenza&f=false) del "Nuovo dizionario dei sinonimi della lingua italiana" descrive bene l'espressione.

Comment: Ah, il Tommaseo! Bravo @VincenzoOliva.

Answer (score 1):

Direi che il significato potrebbe essere quello di "forzarsi" o "costringersi" a fare qualcosa, sottintendendo una mancanza di voglia/desiderio di compiere l'azione.

Tuttavia, è un'espressione che non ho mai sentito. Personalmente, la trovo brutta. Ti consiglierei di non usarla, i verbi che ti ho suggerito sono molto più adatti e meno colloquiali.

Comment: In realtà ha una connotazione più forte, dai un'occhiata al link nel mio commento sopra. Però anch'io non l'avevo mai sentita.

Comment: Grazie, abbiamo postato contemporaneamente, quindi non avevo letto. Comunque non sono granché d'accordo con la definizione nel link, soprattutto riguardo l'analogia tra forza e violenza che, a mio modesto parere, hanno poco a che spartire.

Comment: Personalmente ritengo che la distinzione tra “farsi forza” e “farsi violenza” sia effettivamente quella che descrive il Tommaseo, ma probabilmente l'amica (o la mica) dell'OP esagerava un po' e non intendeva veramente “farsi violenza” come descritto lì, ma solo, appunto, forzarsi a fare qualcosa.

Comment: Personalmente, ho sentito e usato questa espressione in casi molto particolari. Penso anche io, come @DaG che l'uso, nel caso proposto, sia esagerato, per dire che ci si deve sforzare davvero molto. Sarebbe quindi utile avere un contesto più ampio, con esempi di frasi complete.